# How to write a function with more than 3 parameters in J?

Tags: j

For example, how to write the function g=(x-y)/(x-z)?
I know how to write the function with 2 parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use variable matching:

```
f =: 3 : 0
'x y z' =. y
(x-y)%(x-z)
)

f 1; 2; 3
0.5
f 1 2 3 
0.5
f 1.5; 2; 0.5
_0.5
```

Another way is to treat your variables as an array `v` -> `x y z` and define your function as a series of array operations. For example:

- multiply and add `+/` `1 _1 0` * `x y z`,
- multiply and add `+/` `1 0 _1` * `x y z`,
- divide `%/`

This can be written as:

```
g =: 3 :'%/ F (+/ . *) y'
```

where F is

```
1 _1  0
1  0 _1
```

:

```
g 1 2 3 
0.5
g 1.5 2 0.5
_0.5
```

You can take this too far and write:

```
 h =: 3 : '((0{y) - (1{y))  % ((0{y) - (2{y))'
```

but you probably shouldn't.