# How to write a function for three columns of numbers in J?

Tags: j

I need to write a function that I just need to input three cols of number and it will out puts a col of number. So they can calculate in each row and finally get just one row number. For example,X= 1 2 3, Y = 2 3 4, Z= 0 1 2, calculate (x-z)/(y-z), so the output is  0.5 0.5 0.5

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have pretty much stated how it could be solved if you convert your math notation to J (also use `=:` as assignment rather than `=`)

```
   X=: 1 2 3
   Y=: 2 3 4
   Z=: 0 1 2
   (X-Z)%(Y-Z) NB. doesn't need second parenthesis pair (X-Z)%Y-Z also works
0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Reading again you wanted columns of numbers instead of rows, so we'll just change the rows to columns using monadic `,.` "Ravel Items" which takes each item and makes it a row. In this case the each item is an atom and the rows are made into columns and the result is a column.

```
   ex=: ,.X
   why=: ,. Y
   zed=: ,. Z
   ex
1
2
3
   why
2
3
4
   zed
0
1
2
   (ex-zed)%why-zed
0.5
0.5
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471661/how-to-write-a-function-with-more-than-3-parameters-in-j), you can box or shape the arguments to pass arbitrary shapes:

```
 f =: 3 : 0                                                                                                                                                 
'x y z' =. y
(x-z)%(y-z)                                                                                                                                                  
)

f 1 2 3
 2    
f (1 2 3);(2 3 4);(0 1 2)
 0.5 0.5 0.5

f (2 3 $ 5 4);(2 3$ 6 4 2);(2 3$ 7 5)
 2        1      0.4
_1 0.666667 0.333333


f i.3 2 4 3  NB. Input shape (3 a b c...), output shape a b c...
 2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2

 2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2
```